# Opening a test page in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing

I am starting to work with Selenium, so I created (what I thought) was a quick test script to simply open a page within my company's intranet.

I wasn't sure where exactly I was supposed to download the dependencies for Selenium, so I created a folder on my development server called "TESTING", and used the command prompt to install Selenium:

```
 npm install selenium-webdriver
```

The install appears to be successful, as it reads "added 46 packages from 79 contributors..."

Inside my TESTING directory, I can see the node_modules directory was added, as well as the package-lock.json file.

I then created an index.php file that only has the following:

```
<h1>hello world</h1>
<button type="submit" name="btnI">Click Me</button>
```

Here is sample.js, which includes the following script that is supposed to open index.php:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
        withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
        build();

driver.get("https://development.usa.company.com/testing/index.php");

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnI')).click();
```

I go back to the cmd prompt and run the following command:

```
node sample.js
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. 
Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from 
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html 
and ensure it can be found on your PATH.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Athens Holloway suggestion, all I simply needed to do was run the following command in the terminal:

```
npm install chromedriver
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to add the PATH to `chromedriver.exe` into your system Environment Variables.

1. Install chromedriver.exe -- note the file path to the install directory
2. Search Windows for `Environment Variables` and click "Environment Variables.." to edit them
3. Edit the 'Path' variable
4. After all the other file paths that appear, add "C:\Path\To\ChromeDriver\Directory\chromedriver.exe", separated by semicolon from the other paths.

This guide may help: https://developers.refinitiv.com/sites/default/files/How%20To%20Add%20ChromeDriver%20To%20System%20Variables_0.pdf